# How do I properly initialize / define an object of the Text Class in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, constructor, entity

I am working with Google App engine for a project. One of the classes it uses is called the "Text" class. (Link for documentation is here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text)

I am having trouble figuring out how to initialize the variable properly as one of the parameters I am using requires I pass in a Text object and no matter what I do, I can only initialize it with null, which of course creates a null pointer error.

I have tried the following without Success:

```
//Code
Text text = new Text(); //Cannot be initialized this way
Text text; //This will work, but it will say it is not initialized and will create a null pointer
Text text = "stuff"; //Nope
Text text = newInstance(); //Nope
```

What I am trying to accomplish is initialize the object with something other than null and then use it to pass it to a separate methods.

Perhaps I am reading the documentation wrong and just need a fresh pair of eyes. Anyone have any experience with these Text class objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation you linked, the constructor needs a string.
So you would have to try it like this:

```
Text text = new Text("stuff");
```

Comment: You beat me to it by about 60 seconds! Win! Thanks for your help.